# Notification Hubs of Windows Azure for Windows phone 8 not working

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8, windows-phone-8, notifications

Hello friends is any missing on this [Notification Hubs for Wp8](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/get-started-notification-hubs-wp8/) link. i know this not a right question but it is not working in my case. i am able to see the messages coming on my sampleNotificationhub dashboard of windows azure account but not able to get the toast notification.

i have checked the connection string problem too for making sure here is my phone app connection string..

```
 var hub = new NotificationHub("samplenotificationhub", "connectionstring");
            await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString());
```

and my windows store app sending toast notification string is this..

```
NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("connection string", "samplenotificationhub");
        string toast = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
               "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>Hello from a .NET App!</wp:Text1>" +
               "</wp:Toast> " +
            "</wp:Notification>";
        await hub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
```

will you please let me now what i am missing or thr is missing something from link..any help and suggestion is appreciated.
**one more thing i am testing it on Emulator**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Friends I just solved the problem it may be due to some point but when i implemented it again then it is working I have checked the two codes but still not able to get any difference 
so my motive here to answer this question is to make everybody sure that the [Notification hub for Wp8](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/get-started-notification-hubs-wp8/) is fully functional no need of anything else. you can follow it directly.Hope it help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `<wp:Text2 />` and `<wp:Param />` elements in your XML payload.

The `wp:Param` element can be empty but the `wp:Text2` element cannot be.

Comment: Matt i have added these two also but not working..have you checked the notification hub link..is thr any thing missing from this link..or any thing has to be implemented first..plese see it..

Comment: Matt The suggestion you have given is appreciated but toast payload is working without what you have suggested  just wanted to update you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below tag

```
 string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                   "<wp:Toast>" +
                        "<wp:Text1> title </wp:Text1>" +
                        "<wp:Text2> subtitle </wp:Text2>" +
                        "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
                   "</wp:Toast> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";
```

Comment: this problem is not from this issue..i have just solved it..btw thanks